# LCD display regularly loses input from PC

Tags: windows-7, display

For the last a few weeks I have been experiencing a really annoying problem with my PC. It runs for around 10 hours. Then suddenly the LCD monitor goes completely blank (display "no signal"). When it happened the first time. I thought the video cable from PC to LCD monitor was loose. But after I tighten it the same thing happens regularly. Now I have to manually reboot every 8 or 10 hours - NOT good.

I am wondering anybody knows where the problem is ? My PC is 6 years old but I would consider buying a new one as the last resort.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a computer i am working on with the same symptoms, except it has gotten to the point where there is no video output at all. This is a Z77 motherboard with Intel processor graphics, so it could either be the motherboard or the processor, next step is installation of a discrete graphics card

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess my problem is the same - there is no video output at all. Unfortunately I don't know how to detect whether there is video output. I replaced my video card 2 years ago. Guess the retailer gave me a bogus one and I will need another one now.

Comment: Swap known good hardware to diagnose hardware.  When it goes out, swap in a known good monitor.  Also, connect the monitor to a known good computer or laptop, most people have 2 computers or know someone that they can borrow something with a video output.  Also, wiggle the cable on both ends while someone watches the monitor to see if you can have ANY effect on the screen to narrow down the culprit.

Comment: Also notice if your computer is still working mainly via the HDD light; can key in the shut down command from the keyboard without looking and get the HDD light to work, and eventually shutdown the computer.  In windows 7, you just hit ctrl-alt-delete twice.  If you can get the HDD to work, it means your computer is not frozen and it is isolated to a video connection (possibly internal to the monitor too) issue.  As a note, if your video card is failing, it can lock up and freeze your computer as well.  It is highly likely it is a video issue though, not other hardware issue.

Comment: Today the screen goes blank while the PC was playing MP3's. I found that MP3 was "stuck". So I believe it is not just the video output. The whole system was frozen. HDD is on tho.

Anyways I am going to buy a new video card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replaced the video card and this problem goes away.